# I am getting error when run gatsby project

Tags: gatsby

D:\gatsby-site>npm run develop

> gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop D:\gatsby-site

> gatsby develop

ERROR

There was a problem loading plugin "gatsby-plugin-sharp". Perhaps you need to install its package?
Use --verbose to see actual error.

ERROR #10226  CONFIG

Couldn't find the "gatsby-plugin-sharp" plugin declared in "D:\gatsby-site\gatsby-config.js".

Tried looking for a local plugin in D:\gatsby-site\plugins\gatsby-plugin-sharp.

Tried looking for an installed package in the following paths:

- D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\load-themes\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\gatsby\dist\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\gatsby\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp
- D:\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp

not finished open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.115s

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop: `gatsby develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-23T05_28_39_384Z-debug.log

Comment: Node Version: v13.14.0 , npm Version: 6.14.4  git version: git version 2.30.0.windows.1 , git version 2.30.0.windows.1

Answer (score 1):

> There was a problem loading plugin "gatsby-plugin-sharp". Perhaps you
> need to install its package? Use --verbose to see actual error.

Just run `npm install gatsby-plugin-sharp` if you are using the plugin in your `gatsby-config.js` file.

Delete your package-lock.json, your cache (by `gatsby clean`) and your `node_modules`  and run a fresh `npm install` again.

Comment: i have the same error but with `gatsby-plugin-transformer` - did all of the above, but i'm still getting `There was a problem loading plugin "gatsby-plugin-transformer". Perhaps you need to install its package?` and `Failed to resolve gatsby-plugin-transformer unreachable`. any pointers as to what the problem might be?

Comment: Run npm install `gatsby-plugin-transformer` among the commands above (`gatsby-clean`, etc). I would suggest, in addition, installing the `windows-build-tools` by `npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015`

Comment: aaa i use a mac

Comment: Then simply omit last command. But you need to install missing libraries